# how to pass this var to function

Tags: c#, function, windows-phone-8.1, ienumerable, var

**This method generates var result:**

```
private void GraphApi_Facebook()
{
    var fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);
    fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
    {   if (e.Error != null)
        {                 
            return;
        }

        var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();        
        SaveDataToClass(result); // >>> This is wrong           
    }
}
```

**How to pass result to SaveDataToClass()?**

```
private async void SaveDataToClass()
{
    CoreDispatcher dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {

        singletonInstance.facebook_name = (string)result["name"];
        singletonInstance.facebook_firstname = (string)result["first_name"];        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`var` is not a *type*.According to your code the type of result is  `IDictionary<string, object>`, so you should just add a parameter to your method of type `IDictionary<string, object>`

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the signature of `SaveDataToClass` method to the following:

```
private async void SaveDataToClass(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
```

Then you can pass there the `result`  since it's type is `IDictionary<string, object>`.

**Note**

As already Selman22 has pointed out, `var` is not a type. It's a syntactic sugar. When you code will be compiled the type of result would be `IDictionary<string, object>`.

Instead of writing this:

```
IDictionary<string, object> result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
```

You have the ability to write this:

```
var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
```

and during the compilation the type of `result` would be inferred by the type of the value you assign.

Answer (score 0):

change the signature of SaveDataToClass to accept the type of 'result':

```
private async void SaveDataToClass(IDictionary<string, object> result)
{
    . . . 
}
```